# How credit card billing works?

Tags: credit-card, billing

On many websites like Amazon Web Services offering pay-as-you-go and on demand pricing the websites charge the credit card.
How does this work? Can they charge any amount if they wish? What if bill exceeds credit card limit?How do they ensure they get the money?

Basically let's say I make a million dollar bill which will not be available in that bank account credit card's line of credit how will be billed?

Comment: Basically let's say I make a million dollar bill which will not be available in that bank account credit card's line of credit how will be billed?

Comment: They will come after you for the money, with a collections agency if necessary.

Comment: So everyone using EC2 is at risk.

Comment: Does anyone know any prepaid hosting?

Comment: AWS does prepaid hosting, just pick something that has a set price. There's many things that have a set cost per hour which you can just multiply by 720 (or 748 to be safe) to get your cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a card is charged more than the credit limit (which is generally clearly defined when you apply for a given card), the payment will fail.

The vast majority of companies also have internal risk models which do not allow random customers to run up large bills as they are fundamentally on the hook for it if the customer can't pay as it's their resources being consumed.

AWS for example would never let an unknown customer randomly run up a million dollar tab on a single new credit card regardless - they would intervene and want more information/KYC on the customer and their usage/background etc.